# Retrieving IP Address from DAO layer

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, dao

I use spring-acegi and I want retreive ip address from DAO layer. When I use something like:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
if (auth != null) {
    WebAuthenticationDetails details1 = ((WebAuthenticationDetails)auth.getDetails());
    if (details1 != null) {
        userIp = details1.getRemoteAddress();
    }
}
```

on the moment of authentication auth is null and I can't retreive ip address.

Also I tried to get the IP address through

```
String remoteAddress = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
       .getRequest().getRemoteAddr();
```

but get a compile error (we use GWT).

Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you mean by DAO layer? Is this during authentication?

Comment: Why not create one more filter (ore use existing), and get ip from HttpRequest and store it in static ThreadLocal variable for using in your DAO?

Comment: what is the exception thrown ?

Answer (score 0):

Move your

```
String remoteAddress = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getRemoteAddr();
```

code into some class **outside** of  **client** and **shared** packages. Look into your app *.gwt.xml descriptor. For example if you have com/domain/App.gwt.xml as a GWT descriptor and your source packages are declared as

```
<source path="client" />
<source path="shared" />
```

then you must write your code outside of **com.domain.client** and **com.domain.shared** packages.

Consider some refactoring of your code. If you DAO layer absolutely need know about IP then it will be better to send it as a parameter to some method call.